# Using two Controllers in the same view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a page in which I display the list of Categories, I want to Add a form in the same page to remove a desired Category without creating another View for the Remove form
[image]

This was my attempt of adding the Delete IActionResult using a Tuple.

```
namespace MvcProject.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {

       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Category> CatList = _db.Categories;
            var tuple = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Category>, Category>(CatList,new Category()) ;
            
            return View(tuple);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Delete(Category IDtoRemove)
        {
            _db.Categories.Attach(IDtoRemove);
            _db.Categories.Remove(IDtoRemove);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

and the Index View

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Category>,Category>


        <tbody >
        @{
                var r = from q in Model.Item1 orderby q.Id select q;
        foreach (var obj in r)
        {
        <tr class="table-secondary">
        <td style="width:7%">@obj.Id</td>
        <td>@obj.Name</td>
        <td>@obj.DisplayOrder</td>
        </tr>
        }
        }
        </tbody>
</table>



        <form method="post"  class="col-3">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="number" asp-for="Item2.Id"  class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="ID To Remove">
            <label>ID To Remove</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Need more info in what is not working in order to give the resolution

Comment: @SundarBabuManoharan Simply i cannot pass the "ID value" i submit in the form to the Delete Post ActionResult "public IActionResult Delete(Category IDtoRemove)" 
so that i can delete the record

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting an object in the controller, but only passing an id in on the form.

Try updating your controller to take the id

```cs
public IActionResult Delete(int categoryId)
{
    // Use the id to find the category you're targeting, E.G.
    var category = _db.Categories.First(c => c.Id == categoryId);

    // Now remove that from the collection
    _db.Categories.Remove(category);

    // Update the database
    _db.SaveChanges();

    // Return to the index page
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simply i cannot pass the "ID value" i submit in the form to the Delete
> Post

If you want to pass the ID value to the Delete post, you can use name attribute to bind the value.  You can refer to the below code to change your code:

1. form:

```
     <form method="post" asp-action="Delete" class="col-3">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="number" name="IDtoRemove" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="ID To Remove">
                <label>ID To Remove</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</button>
        </form>
```

2.delete post:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Delete(int IDtoRemove)
        { 
            var category =  _db.Categories.Find(IDtoRemove);
            _db.Categories.Remove(category);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
```

result:

[image]

Read [controller methods and views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.